# Response cannot cast to JSON

Tags: java, json, spring

Inside my application I am triggering below code

```
RestTemplate client=new RestTemplate();
if(ipaddress.length>0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ipaddress.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(baseUrl+"/grid/api/proxy?id="+ipaddress[i]);
        ResponseEntity<Object> object= client.getForEntity(baseUrl+"/grid/api/proxy?id="+ipaddress[i], Object.class);
        System.out.println(object);
    }
}
```

The result object return is shown below:

```
<200 OK,{success=true,
         msg=proxy found !,
         id=http://192.168.3.37:5555, 
         request={class=org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest, 
                  id=null, 
                  name=null, 
                  description=null, 
                  configuration={port=5555, 
                                 servlets=[], 
                                 host=192.168.3.37, 
                                 Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Anoop\IEdriver\IEDriverServer.exe=, 
                                 cleanUpCycle=5000, 
                                 Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Anoop\chromeDriver\chromedriver.exe=, 
                                 browserTimeout=0, 
                                 hubHost=localhost, 
                                 registerCycle=5000, 
                                 capabilityMatcher=org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher, 
                                 newSessionWaitTimeout=-1, 
                                 hub=http://localhost:4444/grid/register, 
                                 url=http://192.168.3.37:5555, 
                                 remoteHost=http://192.168.3.37:5555, 
                                 register=true, 
                                 throwOnCapabilityNotPresent=true, 
                                 nodePolling=5000, 
                                 proxy=org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy, 
                                 browser=browserName=firefox, 
                                 maxSession=5, 
                                 role=node, 
                                 jettyMaxThreads=-1, 
                                 hubPort=4444, 
                                 timeout=300000}, 
                  capabilities=[{seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, 
                                 platform=WIN8_1, 
                                 browserName=firefox}, 
                                {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, 
                                 platform=WIN8_1, 
                                 browserName=chrome}, 
                                {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, 
                                 platform=WIN8_1, 
                                 browserName=internet explorer}]}},
        {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], 
         Content-Length=[1185], 
         Server=[Jetty(7.x.y-SNAPSHOT)]}>
```

If I use a `JSONObject` here instead of `Object` in the response entity method I get`{}`

How it is possible to convert `Object` to `JSONObject` ?

**Note**: my application is not a web application.

Comment: please provide more details, so that we can help you

Comment: I think you need `object.getBody()`to get only the JSON content.

Answer (score 0):

The following code you can use in application-context.xml while configuring the RestTemplate.

```
<beans:bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClientFactory" />
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter" />
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter" />
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller" />
                </constructor-arg>
            </beans:bean>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="jsonConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="annotationMethodHandlerAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</beans:bean>
```

Hope this stuff helps you.Let me known if any doubt.

Comment: Thanks Darshan,In this context ,this application is not a web application

Answer (score 0):

```
ResponseEntity<Object> object= client.getForEntity(baseUrl+"/grid/api/proxy?id="+ipaddress[i], Object.class);
```

Here you can pass what object you want, i will suggest if you know the returning object structure to create one dummy mixin class and HttpMessage converter will be responsible for converting it to your dummy class. If you want other JSON provider to be responsible for deserializing you can pass String in the `ResponseEntity<T>` and deserialize it manually.

sample usage :

```
ResponseEntity<Identifier> postForEntity = postForEntity = getTemplate().postForEntity(builder.toUri(), entity, Identifier.class);
        logger.info("creating creative result : "+postForEntity.getBody());
```